# Moongose: .populate on key with white space doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, schema, populate

I'm using Express and Mongoose to do some database actions. When trying to populate a path where the key includes a whitespace, it basically get's ignored.

MongoDB Model:

```
const OrgCrimeSchema = new Schema({
  gracePeriod: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  Technical: {
    description: String,
    difficulty: Number,
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  },
  'Social Engineering': { // This one causes issues
    description: String,
    difficulty: Number,
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  },
});
```

Find + Populate:

```
const now = Date.now();
const allOrgCrimes = await OrgCrime.find({ gracePeriod: { $lte: now } })
    .populate('Technical.owner', 'name')
    .populate('Social Engineering.owner', 'name');

console.log(allOrgCrimes['Social Engineering'][0].owner); 
//5fca3b4a86e77b5c8e58b683

console.log(allOrgCrimes['Technical'][0].owner); 
// { name: 'npc_alice', _id: 5fae6d7ee60018434108369c }
```

I assume the path is not being populated because of a white space in the key. I've tried both dot notation and typing `{path: 'Social Engineering', select: 'name -id'}`, without luck.

Is there any way around this without having to rewrite the schema structure?

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no way, if we wanted to populate multiple paths at the same time there is this way

for exmaple

```
Story
.find(...)
.populate('book author') // space delimited path names
.exec()
```

you can see space delimited path names.

When you pass a key with space,mongoose consider it as populate multiple

Answer (score 0):

As poined out by Mohammad Yaser Ahmadi, there is no solution to this issue today because of populate assumes you're populating multiple instead of trying to read a path name with a space in between. How I 'solved' this was to rewrite the model to this:

```
const OrgCrimeSchema = new Schema({
  gracePeriod: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  roles: [{
    role: String,
    description: String,
    difficulty: Number,
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  }]
})
```

And then the populate actually get's easier:

```
.populate('roles.owner', 'name')
```